# python **kwargs and threading.Timer not working

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import threading

def test(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print("The value of {} is {}".format(key, value))

main_var = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}

test( a = main_var["a"], b = main_var["b"], c = main_var["c"] )

test( **main_var )

threading.Timer(3, test, **main_var).start()
```

The first 2 calls to the test function produce the expected output, i,e

> The value of a is 1
>
> The value of b is 2
>
> etc

However the 3rd call using threading.Timer produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    threading.Timer(3, test, **main_var).start()
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong to get this error. I need to be able to pass a dictionary (in this case main_var) to the function inside the timer. It works great outside of the timer, but not inside. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the **main_var sends the items of main_var dict as keyword argument to the Timer function instead they should be sent to test function. You need to use kwargs parameter to send arguments to the function to be called.

Please check below:

```
import threading

def test(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print("The value of {} is {}".format(key, value))

main_var = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}

test( a = main_var["a"], b = main_var["b"], c = main_var["c"] )

test( **main_var )

threading.Timer(3, test, kwargs=main_var).start()
```